# Is it possible to control polymer-expressions firing?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm developing a mobile application and love using Polymer specifically for importing in custom elements. The application relies on a custom element that does canvas drawing on requestAnimationFrame. As a result I've been looking at Chrome's Timeline Console to see if I can shave off as many operations as possible to keep the application buttery smooth. During my analysis there are many things on my end I can optimize. But I also noticed a polymer based timed functions:

[image]

*For lack of a better term I'm going to call this polling (I'd love to know at a high level what Polymer is doing here)*. Is it possible to stop this polling and fire this update myself? Since I'm only using the imports and custom elements, I wanted to test and see if I could get away with updating polymer only during the initialization of the page and sparingly during the drawing / requestAnimationFrame view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `platform.js` code detecting `Object.observe` polyfill and polling the dirty-check mechanism.

There is no polling on platforms with native `Object.observe`.

If you want to use standard `platform.js`, then you can turn off the polling thusly:

```
clearInterval(Platform.flushPoll);
```

and call it periodically this way:

```
Platform.flush();
```

If you are hardcore about

> I'm only using the imports and custom elements

Then you can also avoid the polling by using those polyfills directly instead of `platform.js` (giving up data-binding and `polymer.html` support).

Answer (score 1):

Polymer uses polling to flush data changes. There's more info on how data change propagate in here: http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#flush. Polling goes away when `Object.observe` is turned on by default! For browsers that don't have it, Polymer will continue to do polling.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It looks like `polymer.flush()` will be very useful. In the interim for mobile applications is there a way to turn the polling off entirely? That way I can control the executions of `polymer.flush()`?